# In MapBasic, how do I register a table in XLS format that has a different range from one execution to another?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I need my application to be able to register an XLS table that does not have a set range.  One time it may be A2:AL10000, the next it may be A2:AL2000, etc.  I have not seen this anywhere in the reference manual.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way around this is to use Mapbasic to first import the unknown XLS without a specified range. Then check how many columns/rows were imported, close the XLS and then reopen with the correct range.

The process/code is detailed here:
http://testdrive.mapinfo.com/TechSupp/MIProd.nsf/8525626e005d691e8525626d0074fc65/f6487f3b430d322e8525667a004fcb48?OpenDocument